# Run Singularity on a shared GitLab runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, openmpi, singularity-container

My main goal is to implement some tests that use OpenMPI and parallel computing but on a shared GitLab runner. I have been unsuccessful in doing so using Docker because of the limitation of being in an unprivileged environment.
Since I also had to work on a Singularity image, I've been recently trying to implement it in GitLab CI without much success as there isn't a lot of documentation.

I have been able to retrieve an image from Sylabs Cloud but I am not able to use the **run/shell/exec** commands.
The picture below shows what I get.

```
$ singularity shell --userns image.sif
INFO:    Converting SIF file to temporary sandbox...
FATAL:   while handling image.sif: while extracting image: %!w(<nil>)
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

From what  I understand it has to do with some privileged issue again.
I have tried using the **--userns** flag and changing the setting to an unprivileged installation as indicated here https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.5/admin-guide/user_namespace.html but apparently the issue wasn't linked to this.

Here is the content of my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
test_singularity:
  stage: test-singularity
  before_script:
    - echo "Running test inside Singularity container"
  image:    
    name: quay.io/singularity/singularity:v3.10.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  script: 
    - echo "${SINGULARITY_TOKEN}" | singularity remote login
    - singularity pull image.sif library://...
    - sed -i -e 's/allow setuid = yes/allow setuid = no/' /usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf
    - singularity shell --userns image.sif 
    - echo "Inside Singularity container"
    - echo "exit"
```

If there is anything else I could provide that could help solve this issue please let me know.
If there are other solutions to be able to run tests with parallel computing using OpenMPI on a shared runner I am open to hear about them as well.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

`singularity shell` starts an interactive shell session, it does not mean that all following steps are run inside that shell. Create a script with the commands you want to run inside the image and use `singularity exec image.sif my_script.sh`.

More broadly, the [gitlab shared runner resources are limited](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html) and likely not ideal for testing intense parallel workloads.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the reply. 
Sorry I should have cleaned up my .yml file a bit more. The commands after are not really relevant as I was just trying to make any of the run/exec/shell command work (they all return the same error) but thanks for the tip!

I am actually not running very intense workloads as only test examples will be run. However, it is important they are run in parallel to ensure it will work well. But it seems like it is difficult to do on a shared runner..